# Regex to remove dash and everything after it

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a function to remove the dash and everything that comes after it from a title. 
This is the JS

```
<script>
(function() {
var str2 = document.querySelector('.dash-remove').innerHTML;
   var txt2 = str2.replace(/ -.*$/g,"");
   document.querySelector('.dash-remove').innerHTML = txt2;
})();
</script>
```

The Html is something like this

```
<h2 class="dash-remove">Testing - this function</h2>
```

However this isn't working, it's not removing the dash or the text after.

I've tried just removing the dash like this:

```
<script>
(function() {
var str2 = document.querySelector('.dash-remove').innerHTML;
   var txt2 = str2.replace('-',"");
   document.querySelector('.dash-remove').innerHTML = txt2;
})();
</script>
```

And this works so I assume it's something to do with the regex? any ideas?

Comment: The regex working fine. Is there anything else thats diffrent?

Comment: @user6537157 I'm just thionking- could it be because there are more than one element with that class and it stops after the first one?

Comment: @MariaL yes, that would explain it. Look for the example using `forEach` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#Examples).

Comment: Try jQuery instead. `$('.dash-remove`).each( ... );`

Comment: @MariaL See updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in OP's comments, this may be due to the class being present multiple times. You should then use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) along with [`NodeList#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) :

```js
(function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.dash-remove').forEach(item => {
    item.innerHTML = item.innerHTML.replace(/ -.*$/g, '');
  });
})();
```

```html
The Html is something like this

<h2 class="dash-remove">Testing - this function</h2>
<h2 class="dash-remove">Testing - that function</h2>
```

Comment: Issue is that the titles are loaded dynamically so querySelectorAll doesn't work

Comment: @MariaL Then move the `document.querySelectorAll` part to whenever the titles are loaded dynamically. And if more are added later, you can adjust their title before displaying them.